# When I hover on "No hats for me, please", it's too dark

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

When I click the snowflake icon, there is `No hats for me please` button. But when I hover on it, it's too dark. Can we change it to another color?

Change this to a brighter color (white? lightblue?), and please remove the underline :

Edit: maybe it should stay dark, but please remove the underline. it looks very strange

> When I start rejecting the fun, things become too dark

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the text should remain white, in line with all the other blue buttons with white text on the SE network.

Comment: Love the title. _When I start rejecting the fun, things become too dark._

Comment: @Yaakov Um why is this [tag:status-completed]? this is not fixed...

Comment: @ppwater this is the way that I decided to fix it. =completed

Comment: @YaakovEllis Ah, didn't know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yaakov Ellis, this is fixed now.

> @ppwater this is the way that I decided to fix it. =completed – Yaakov Ellis♦

When hovered:

[image]